# Adding request header to a graphql request using HttpGraphQlClient client

Tags: graphql, spring-graphql

Is there any way to attach a header at the request level to HttpGraphQlClient without client regeneration. I want to attach individual session id of the user to the graphql request.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about how you're getting this session id, I think you can use an `ExchangeFilterFunction` for that:

```
ClientSessionFilterFunction sessionFilter = new ClientSessionFilterFunction();
WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder().filter(sessionFilter);



public class ClientSessionFilterFunction implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

    @Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
        Mono<String> sessionId = //...
        return sessionId.flatMap(id -> {
            request.headers().add("Session-Id", id);
            return next.exchange(request);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.1.0-RC1/reference/html/#client-httpgraphqlclient) is this:

> Once HttpGraphQlClient is created, you can begin to execute requests using the same API, independent of the underlying transport. **If you need to change any transport specific details, use mutate() on an existing HttpGraphQlClient to create a new instance with customized settings.**

So my class looks like this:

```java
@Component
public class MyGraphqlClient {
    @Autowired
    private HttpGraphQlClient graphQlClient; // a preconfigured bean, used as a prototype

    public Mono<MyResponse> getCompany(String input) {
        return graphQlClient.mutate()
                .header("x-my-header", "MY_VALUE") // Here I set my request-specific header
                .build()

                .documentName("NAME OF THE RESOURCE in resources/graphql-documents")
                .variable("input", input)
                .retrieve("QUERY_NAME")
                .toEntity(MyResponse.class)
                ;
    }
}
```

It is not completely "without client regeneration" as you requested, but at least the pre-generated client is re-used as a prototype, and I don't have to set up all its parameters again. And it's in accordance with the official documentation. I would like a better solution, too :)